# Xamarin Forms / Xamarin.Essentials - How to ensure that "Always Allow" Location permission has been granted from within the iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I have a Xamarin Forms app running on iOS, which needs to receive location data even when not running in the foreground.

When the app first runs, the user is prompted to grant the location permission, from the options:

> Allow "My App" to use your location?

- Allow Once
- Allow While Using App
- Don't Allow

There is no "Always Allow" option.

If the user selects either "Allow Once", or "Allow While Using App", the app is able to retrieve the devices location, while in the foreground. All good so far.

If I then hit the device's Home button to remove focus from the app, leaving it to run in the background, I am prompted some (random amount of) time after with the iOS prompt:

> Allow "My App" to also use your location even when you are not using the app?

- Keep Only While Using
- Change to Always Allow

If the user selects "Change to Always Allow", everything within the app works fine, including in the background. Just like I need it to.

However, from within the app, I want to do the following:

1. Rather than waiting an indeterminate/unknown amount of time for iOS to get around to prompting the user for the "Always Allow" permission, to ask iOS from within the app to prompt the user for the "Always Allow" permission when the app launches.
2. Check that the required "Always Allow" permission has been granted by the user.

#### Prompt the user for "Always Allow" permission

From within the app, I have tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to make any difference:

```
var permission = new Permissions.LocationAlways();
permission.EnsureDeclared();
```

#### Check that "Always Allow" Permission has been granted

From within the app, I am using the following code to check on the status of the LocationAlways permission.

But, even when the user has just granted "While using the app", and not yet been prompted for "Always Allow", the status of the LocationAlways permission still shows "Granted".

In fact, as far as I can tell, the following 2 lines of code always return the same status:

```
var locationAlwaysPermissionStatus = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationAlways>();
var locationWhenInUsePermissionStatus = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
```

#### Info.plist

These are the relevant entries from Info.plist.

```
  <array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>processing</string>
    <string>location</string>
  </array>
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
  <string>(Always message)</string>
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>(Always and in use message)</string>
  <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>(When in use message)</string>
```

I don't know if it's relevant, but I have had to include entries for all 3 message types, even though, as far as I am concerned, I am only interested in the Always usage.

- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
- NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription
- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

When iOS initially prompts with the options "Allow Once / Allow While Using App / Don't Allow", it uses the "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" message.

...and when iOS eventually prompts the user to grant "Always Allow", it uses the "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" message.

However, I also have to include "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" in the Plist.info, although the message is never displayed, as without it, the app crashes when the app tries to call the "permission.EnsureDeclared()" method.

#### User can manually set the "Always Allow" location permission

I am aware that the user can manually enable the "Always Allow" permission in the app permissions. But, regardless, the app will need to know that the "Always Allow" location permission has indeed been granted, and not just the "While In Use" permission.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: After some version of iOS 13 (perhaps iOS 13.3 or thereabouts) you can initially ask for when in use permission and once you have received that you can ask for "always" permission to trigger the always upgrade dialog. There is no way to get always immediately; this is by design. Additionally, if you do ask for always but the user is only promoted for, and selects, "when in use" you have what is known as "provisional always" permission. There is no way to distinguish between provisional always and always. Again, this is by design.